# Getting Error "Image reader can not be created from -vec samples.vec and -bg negative.txt"

Tags: opencv

I am trying to train **Haar cascade** classifier in **OpenCV** to detect an object using **windows 7**. I fellowed some tutorials online like this one [here](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) but whenever I reached the training stage i got this error [as you can see in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Egg6.png). I tried to find a solution but there is not too much about this subject online. what should i do in this case?

Comment: I had some characters which are not written in capital letter. I corrected it and everything worked fine for me.